# What power is required (in terms of watts) to produce 1 lpm flow of Hydrogen @ STP using electrolysis at 100% efficiency?

Tags: energy, hydrogen

I know that the energy is usually expressed a joules but the test set up I have at the moment comprises of just voltage, current and temperature measurements along with a hydrogen mass flow gauge.
I am trying to estimate the efficiency of a cell arrangement that I've recently had a patent granted.
I've look all over but just cant find a simple definition anywhere.
At the moment it is quite happy at around 1 lpm and around 400 watts input (4 volts @ 100 amps).
I'm in the process of changing the Anode and Cathode formats to experiment with sintered g-c3n4... (lots of interesting stuff to try)... but at the moment I could really do with some help on this measurement please.

Comment: Back of the envelope, I get about 144 amperes for 1 L/min of hydrogen gas at STP. A mole of hydrogen gas at STP is about 22.4 L, you need 2 mol of electrons per mol of hydrogen gas and the charge of a mol of electrons is about 96485 coulombs.

Comment: I calculated 143 W, which clearly indicates that your electrolysis efficiency is lower than expected (e.g., 36%, which is believable).

Comment: I'm reading so many different figures. Elsewhere there are measurements of 39.4 kWh/kg.
Given that there are 11126 L/Kg.... I'm lost.

Comment: @MartinMoore, keep in mind that 1 mole of hydrogen gas has a mass of only 2 grams and occupies 22.4 liters at STP.  A kg of the stuff is 500 times this amount!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is french.

To be a little more precise, the minimum electrical work is equal to the variation of Gibbs free energy : $W=∆G$. The relation between $∆G$ and $∆H$ is $∆G=∆H-T∆S$ with evidently $∆S>0$ for liquid water electrolysis. So we find $∆G<∆H$.

If I am not mistaken, the difference does not seem negligible since we have a Gibbs standard free energy of 237 KJ / mol and a standard enthalpy of 285 KJ / mol.

Using the previous answer, this would lead to a minimum power of 180 W / l (instead of 214 W / l) which decreases the value of the efficiency.

Comment: That's interesting.  I can see the logic there, but then I read tabulated values for the reaction of about 142 MJ/kg, which with the density of H2 and the 1 lpm measurement covert to 213 W.

Comment: After doing some more reading I think your statement $W=∆G$ is correct, but the electrical source would need to provide heat as well correct , i.e. $(Work+ Heat)=∆H$...?

Comment: This is the minimum work: in reversible conditions, without overvoltage, at very very low current...But the thermal energy supplied by the heat source (the atmosphere) in these conditions is indeed taken into account in this minimum work.

Comment: Thanks guys, these comments are helping me to move forward and filter through the mass of information I read.
I've been suspecting an efficiency or around 40 - 50 % so I'm kind of finding my benchmark now. Of course as the temperature rises the game changes yet again and that's before I try a new Anode material.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you would take the "liters per min" of hydrogen measured, convert liters to mass of hydrogen via density, and from there use the formation enthalpy of hydrogen per kg, to obtain Joules/min, and convert to Watts from there.

Editing with additional requested info:
The formation of hydrogen from liquid water represents a definite amount of chemical energy. You just have to convert the L/min flow rate into the equivalent energy. The reaction is:
$ H_2O—> H_2+ \frac{1}{2} O_2$

To find the energy required to perform the reaction, you subtract the formation enthalpies at standard conditions of the products from that of the reactants.  In this case it is simple because both $H_2$ and $O_2$ have formation enthalpies of zero. So take the formation enthalpy of liquid water (absolute value) of $285$  $kJ/mol$ (which matches your cited value of $39.4$  $kWh/kg$ pretty well.  Using the standard density $9×10^{-5}$ $kg/L$ and molecular weight $0.002$ $kg/mol$ of hydrogen gas, you can obtain:

$1 \frac{L}{min} * 9×10^{-5} \frac{kg}{L} * \frac{1}{0.002} \frac{mol}{kg} * 285,000 \frac{J}{mol H_2}$
$= 12.8$  $kJ/min$
or $214$ $Watts$
This puts your machine's efficiency at about 50%.

(Patent attribution......?)

Comment: Aha... you've described a method but this is like an alien language to me. Electronics - I can cope with. 
I imagined that my need was something quite simple but there more I look into it there more tricky it seems to be. 
Elsewhere it says it takes 39.4Kw/h our to make 1kg of H2 - that's 11126 litres but that does not agree with the information above of 144'ish watts!

Comment: I wish my physics & chemistry maths were better (actually I wish it were a lot better). That figure broadly agrees with what I've been finding in general reading around the subject.
So around 50% would be good news indeed as I've not investigated elevated temperatures or different formulations for Anode materials which is on my list of things to do.
So having a benchmark now... it means I can confidently move on.
If I update my patent - you may well get a mention of thanks. :)

Comment: It's been a while since I visited this topic, but I thought I give it an update.
It recently produced over 1 lpm with an input of just 290 W/h of energy
Based on the figure of 214 watts from above, my cell is running at around 73.79% efficiency. 

I've still got to change the Anode and cathode electrodes to something a more catalytic... I'm hoping for another 10% out of it.
Temperature is 35'C.

The other thing I want to try is a zero spaced design. 

I'm looking for sub 2.5 volts across the cell which toll take me to 85%.

More news when I get round to it.

Comment: That's good. But what is W/h? Watts per hour doesn't mean anything. Watt*hrs (multiplied) is an energy